# Why do compilers generate different code for const int& vs const int arguments?

Tags: c++, assembly, g++, language-lawyer

Consider these two functions.

```
int foo(const int& a) {
    return a + 5;
}

int bar(const int a) {
    return a + 5;
}
```

Given these functions, g++-4.9 generates the following code at full optimization.

> ```
> g++-4.9 -std=c++11 -Ofast -march=native -DNDEBUG -fno-exceptions -Wall -S -o test17.S test17.cpp
> ```

```
# foo
movl    (%rdi), %eax
addl    $5, %eax
ret

# bar
leal    5(%rdi), %eax
ret
```

The machine is an x86-64 Mac.

Why is the compiler so "literal minded" here?

My understanding is that references in C++ are usually implemented as pointers but that this is not mandated by the standard. They are best understood as an alias for a variable. The details are left to the implementation.

Given that references need not actually be pointers, it seems like an obvious optimization to generate the same code for both functions. Would it have been illegal to generate the `const int` code for both of these functions? Is there an observable difference between the two functions?

Comment: The ABI mandates that references are passed as pointers. And it does that because the function might look at the address of its argument and not just its value.

Comment: The caller site probably needs to know the difference, so the optimization needs to be agreed between the call site and the called method. Seeing the linker may be involved, it's a hard problem.

Comment: there can be an observable difference in the context of multithreaded application: the value referenced by a might change between the invocation of foo and the evaluation of the returned expression (a+5)

Comment: These are excellent answer-comments. Perhaps they could become answers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You declared your functions with *external linkage*. A compiler that does not (or cannot) perform global program optimizations cannot change interface specification of a function with external linkage for obvious reasons - that function can be called from some other translation unit, which has no knowledge of whether the function's interface specification was "transformed" or not.

If you declare these functions with *internal linkage*, then the compiler will have much more freedom in transforming these functions.

When I declared your functions `static` and compiled them with `gcc -O3 -fno-inline-functions -fno-inline-functions-called-once -fno-inline-small-functions` (in a desperate no-holds-barred attempt to kill any possibility of inlining), they produced identical code

```
_ZL3bari:
.LFB1:
    .seh_endprologue
    leal    5(%rcx), %eax
    ret

_ZL3fooRKi.isra.0:
.LFB3:
    .seh_endprologue
    leal    5(%rcx), %eax
    ret
```

Note that these considerations apply to "trivial" functions only (which is probably what you meant in the first place) with "obvious" (to the compiler) semantics. A "non-trivial" function might cast away the constness of the reference and modify the referee, which is perfectly legal provided the referee itself is modifiable. For this reason in general case it is not possible to replace a const reference parameter with a value parameter.

Comment: From what you pointed out, I was also able to get the same code simply by declaring foo() and bar() static and calling them from wrapper functions.

Comment: @black: OK, let's make it `-O3` (I ran it with `-O4` actually.) The more, the better... :)